# Ruby on Rails 4 - Where statement crashes when nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I am trying to search a database of names by both last name and maiden name.  However, if the maiden name is nil, then the search crashes.  I created a work around with an if/then statement, but want to learn the proper (cleaner) way to do this in ruby.

```
  if user.maiden_name.nil?        
    x = Alumni.where(firstname: user.first_name, lastname: user.last_name)
  else
    x = Alumni.where(firstname: user.first_name, lastname: [user.last_name, user.maiden_name])
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you receive when the search crashes?

Comment: What Neven said, because nil maiden_name should be fine.

Comment: You are right, the error was actually on the .upcase, which was crashing when there was a nil maiden name. Is there a way to add upcase on the sql statement for the non-null names?

Comment: using: user.maiden_name.try(:upcase) seemed to work.  Would this be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you're on ruby 2.3.0  the safe navigation operator is available which is quite similar to the try method. There's more info in the release notes: 

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid `nil` value in `where`'s condition clause by adding `#compact` applied to args array, as follows:

```
Alumni.where(firstname: user.first_name,
   lastname: [user.last_name, user.maiden_name].compact)
```

But is it that you wish really?

Comment: Thank you! That's a really good tip, and it does actually work for this scenario as well.

Comment: Is there any way to do this if I was using this method:      Alumni.where("lastname = ?", [user.last_name, user.maiden_name])

Comment: @user3461645 `Alumni.where("lastname IN ?",...) ` but why do you need to use the old style args to where?

Comment: The only reason I need to do that is because I need to use an OR in the statement.

Comment: @user3461645 so use arel instead